# How to SELECT number of hours worked in specifc weeks using postresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find out how many hours employees worked on specific weeks in April and March.

When trying to find the total hours worked (numeric value), I'm given a "Date Out of Range" error. I'm fairly sure I made a simple mistake in my select queries. Could someone point out to me what's wrong?

How would you make a select query if you only wanted to get the number of hours worked from 2015-04-05 to 2015-04-11? If I can figure out how to get the numbers for that specified week, then that'll help me with the other weeks I need to look up as well. Pardon the newbish questions, I'm still new to SQL with very little experience.

```
SELECT

SUM(CASE WHEN hours_worked BETWEEN dateadd(ww,-1,'2015-04-05') AND dateadd(ww,-00,'2015-04-05') THEN r.hours_worked END) AS hours_worked

SUM(CASE WHEN hours_worked BETWEEN dateadd (wk,-1,'2015-3-14') AND dateadd(wk,-0,'2015-3-20')  THEN r.hours_worked END) AS hours_worked
```

Comment: You are using SQL Server syntax, but the question is tagged Postgres.

Comment: is `dateadd` a custom stored procedure? See: http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd

Comment: I'm using Postgres so maybe that's where my issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to write a query similar to yours:

```
SELECT
  name,
  SUM(
    CASE 
    WHEN hours_worked BETWEEN 
      (to_date('2015-04-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '7 days')
      AND to_date('2015-04-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS number_of_records
from test
group by name
```

[`to_date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-formatting.html) function converts a string to a date.

`- interval '7 days'` tells PostgreSQL to go to last week.

Using hints from the query above, you should be able to suit it to your needs.

Comment: thanks for this.

I just tried entering that in my select but I got a bunch of zeros. Will that select query help me get the numeric value of hours worked between the dates of 2015-04-05 to 2015-04-11?

Comment: @AllenM Can you edit your question by posting your table structure, some  example data, query you used, and results you want (not the results you got)? Based on that I can provide help by refining the query